# Where should I install DHCP server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

On enterprise or medium size company where is DHCP server installed?
What is normal practice followed, in terms of DHCP server?

Here, I have DHCP server installed on one of my core switch.

Problem which i face is that my domain controller which is also a DNS server, don't update, if I select dynamic update with secure only.

So I have to keep both — nonsecure & secure dynamic update on my DNS Windows server, which is risky.

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that it is common practice to have Windows do DHCP, since you get all that awesome AD integration (like DNS). That's what Microsoft expects you to do. In any case, I would run it on some kind of server.

Why are you running DHCP from a switch?

Comment: I'm going to setup AD for a very small company. Probably less than 10 computers. So there will be no failover or clustering. I was thinking of keeping the dhcp on the router because just in case the AD box does fail, the users will still be able to get an IP and access the internet. In this scenario, would it be best to keep DHCP service on the router?

Comment: You require failover for dhcp for...?

Comment: @lbanz I'm more of a Linux guy, but don't things go all wonky when the domain controllers go away? Can users still login to their computers if the domain isn't responding? Or have more recent versions of Windows fixed that?

Comment: What if the router fails, no internet and no access to anything on the local network?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin. Its not "fixed" since when your source of authentication goes away you can no longer authenticate.  In the Linux world this is the equivalent of removing ldap or nis and expecting to still have auth work.

Comment: @JimB I figured that - and I wasn't being literal. I was just hopeful Microsoft found a way around that. I do understand how network authentication works. :)

Comment: @RyanBabchishin  Ok, you don't need DHCP for AD to work, and why I asked the OP what is the requirement for DHCP redundancy (consider what happens to existing clients)

Comment: Also, in order for the services that AD offer to work as expected you'd need to have your client's primary DNS pointing at the domain controller, when it goes down so does your dns, making the lack of a dhcp server kind of irrelevant. You could add secondary dns but this will result in slow lookups in the event of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Since DHCP is a lightweight network protocol/service, I usually install it on my router or network gateway. If I also have a DNS server, I configure DHCP to update the DNS when a new lease happens. The advantage of this approach is that since DHCP is a lousy protocol to work through routers (y'know, broadcasts don't go across them, you have to configure a DHCP relay on your router and not every router has that capability...), you can in a easier way, implement it to all your subnets.

Comment: Stefano - You're probably getting downvoted for this answer because ServerFault is geared towards IT professionals, and running DHCP on a router isn't generally considered good enough and it's definitely not enterprise.

Comment: I totally disagree with the opinion that running DHCP on a router isn't good enough for an enterprise environment. For instance, I have an rb1100ahx2 managing around 1200 hosts with DHCP with no problem. Downvoting it just because it is another point of view is just nonsense.

Comment: Disagree all you like, but you're not describing something that would normally be seen in a professionally managed environment

Comment: @Dan, you're off-base here. There is absolutely nothing wrong with running DHCP on a router or other network device. The presumption that doing so is in any way un-professional is inappropriate.

Comment: @EEAA I just find it exceptionally hard to believe that a router can provide all of the required functionality, support and reliability that a large, well managed, enterprise may require.

Comment: actually my downvote was because it doesn't answer the question. The OP says, I can get my DHCP server to update DNS but only when it is unsecure. Where can I put it to update and make it secure. The answer says, get dhcp to update dns when a new lease happens. He is already doing that

Comment: @Drifter104 your first question was "On enterprise or medium size company where is DHCP server installed? What is normal practice followed, in terms of DHCP server?", to which I've answered. 

As far as I know, DDNS on Windows Servers can only be updated from domain members. And since you're running your DHCP server on your core switch, it most probably wouldn't have that capability. 

This article can shine some light on the question:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961412.aspx

Answered now?

Comment: @StefanoMartins not my question and the last part of the question states. `So I have to keep both — nonsecure & secure dynamic update on my DNS Windows server, which is risky`